# RESTful WCF Services with No svc file and No config with parameter binding

Tags: c#, web-services

I already setup the service with No svc file and No config but I need binding parameter with json, I try using postman(google extension) to get in, and I always getting min date in my object class. Isn't possible to do it?

For exmaple:

{ "date" : { "lastdate" : "2012-02-02"}}

this json will binding into method class.

Header

```
POST /DMatchService/Team HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10017
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "Team" : { "lastdate" : "1335205592410"}}
```

Services classes

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetTeam", Method = "POST")]
 public string GetTeam(Team team)
  {
       DatasourceMatchServices svc = new DatasourceMatchServices();
       return date.lastdate.ToString();
   }
```

Classes

```
[DataContract]
    public class Team
    {
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime lastdate { get; set; }
    }
```

Global.cs

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("DMatchService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(DMatchService)));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `post` your data as `json` from an `ajax` call to the `endpoint`.And I don't think you need `DataContract attributes` in this case.

Comment: thx for answer, I trying use POSTMAN to POST data, but it always give me min date to me

Comment: well you need to use a proper `json date format`.Some thing like this :`"\"\\/Date(1335205592410)\\/\"" ` .

Comment: even I send a string, it also get it empty

Comment: try before also same --> public string GetTeam(string date)

If want parameter with object?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx

I follow link to create all code is same